# How to return a list when unit testing DynamoDB PaginatedQueryList

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I have a query statement which returns a `PaginatedQueryList` and I assign it to a List. Then I operate on the list.

```
List<MyClass> entries= mapper.query(MyClass.class, queryExpression);
//Logic to test
Map<String, Map> map = entries.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyClass::getA, MyClass::getB));
....
....
```

I tried to test it like

```
when(mapper.query(eq(MyClass.class), any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class)))
                              .thenReturn((PaginatedQueryList<MyClass>) list);
```

where `list` is `List<MyClass>`(ArrayList) that I construct myself and want to pass it to the main program to test the main logic.

But it throws

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedQueryList

How can I send the list when it executes `mappper.query(..)`.

The motive is to send the list that I constructed to `entries` when executing `mapper.query(..)`.

**NOTE:**

I also tried sending a `mocked` PaginatedQueryList but when it does `entries.stream()` I want to send the actual stream.
I tried like

```
when(paginatedQueryList.stream()).thenReturn(Stream.of(list.get(0), list.get(1)));
```

It throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed
>       at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:229)

**NOTE 2:**

I use `entries.stream()` twice in my logic to test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by sending mocked `PaginatedQueryList` and then send `list.stream()` twice (for each access of `entries.stream()`).

```
when(paginatedQueryList.stream()).thenReturn(list.stream()).thenReturn(list.stream());
```

Any better approaches are welcome.

Comment: can you share the code example where you implemented this?
from where is the paginatedQueryList is coming?
whereas the list is the list I create. And why thenReturn is done twice?

Answer (score 27):

Mockito has some powerful tools for this.

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
when(mapper.query(eq(MyClass.class), any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class)))
    .thenReturn(mock(PaginatedQueryList.class, withSettings().defaultAnswer(new ForwardsInvocations(list))));
```

This will return a mocked `PaginatedQueryList` which forwards all method calls to `list`.

Comment: I was struggling mocking the `query` method on the `DynamoDBMapper` class. This worked great!

Comment: this was a life saver. Thanks.

Comment: I have complex data structure with types and this option does not work well for me. Either I have to make this very complex by using different internal API OR suppress warnings (which I don't want to do). The option provided by @user7 worked fine (mocking `.stream`) in my case.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is a generic solution for mocking PaginatedQueryList in tests (might be useful for googlers, since there's not much answers for this topic).

For my test this worked:

```
    // given
    List<UserDevice> expectedDevices = Arrays.asList(generateUserDevice(USER_ID, DEVICE_ID), generateUserDevice(USER_ID, "deviceId2"));

    PaginatedQueryList listMock = mock(PaginatedQueryList.class);
    when(listMock.listIterator()).thenReturn(expectedDevices.listIterator());
    when(mapper.query(eq(UserDevice.class), any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class))).thenReturn(listMock);

    // when
    List<UserDevice> devices = dao.findAll(USER_ID);

    // then
    assertEquals(expectedDevices, devices);
```

so, as you can see, I mocked the PaginatedQueryList and mocked its *listIterator()* method.

Comment: I tried this but the `query` method was not mocked because it returned null.